# Change the Color of Next Element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out this programming assignment for the last couple of hours but I'm getting stuck on one part. I currently have a program that onclick will randomly pick an element and change its background color. How do I modify the program so that it only changes the color of the adjacent box(right.) So clicking would select the box, change its color, then the next click would change the color of the next box. Keep in mind this needs to be done with only a while loop.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
     Your name does here
     The date goes here
     CISC 131

     A short description of the project goes here
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>this will appear on the tab in the browser</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="Changenxtonclick.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
*{border: 0;
margin:0;
paddig: 0;
}
body{
font-family:"Times New Roman"; serif;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.box
{
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="box" id="box0"></div>
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
<div class="box" id="box3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.onclick = changeBackgroundColor;
}
function changeBackgroundColor()
{
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById(generateId());
    element.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();

}  // Changes the background color of the boxes.
function generateId()
{
    return "box" + getRandomInteger(3);

}
function getRandomRGB() // Uses getRandomInteger to generate random RGB colors.
{
    var red;
    var green;
    var blue;
    var result;
    red = getRandomInteger(255);
    green = getRandomInteger(255);
    blue = getRandomInteger(255);
    result = "rgb("+red+","+green+","+blue+")";
    return result;

}

function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) // Gets a random number on less than upperLimit
{
    var result;
    result = Math.random();
    result = result * (upperLimit + 1);
    result = Math.floor(result);




    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to store the id of the random element? If so the first click would return a random number, and then clicks afterwards could increment the number.

e.g.

```
var selected = getRandomInteger(3); //Generate a random number
window.onload = function()
{
    document.onclick = changeBackgroundColor;
}
function changeBackgroundColor()
{
    var element;
    element = document.getElementById("box"+selected);
    element.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();
    selected = ((selected+1)%4); //Increment the id using mod to loop around.
}
```

Edit:
Naeem's answer is nicer, avoids storing an id :)

Comment: Well this is a good answer too.. Nd thats just storing value in a variable so nothing bad in your answer.. +1

Answer (score 1):

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3zf64t6/

It selects a random element on first click and changes backgrund color and on the next clicks, it changes the color for the next sibling divs

```
function changeBackgroundColor()
{

    if(clicked==0)
    {
    element = document.getElementById(generateId());
    clicked++;

    }else{
         element=element.nextSibling;
        console.log(element);
    }
    element.style.backgroundColor = getRandomRGB();

}
```